# Une personne toujours masculin. Quel pronom est correct?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-personnels

J'ai écrit un conte dans laquelle le protagoniste (!) est nommé « la  prochaine personne » - et il est toujours masculin !

Quel est le pronom personnel conjoint correct ? Par exemple :

> La prochaine personne fut cloué du surprise sur place.  « Quel malheur » dit-il. Puis il  ferma ses  yeux. Enfin, après deux jours, ses amis trouvaient la prochaine personne. « Comment vas-tu ? » ils le questionnaient.

Comment: ... fut cloué**e**

Comment: I must agree with a comment of Mouviciel here under. You're going to face a lot of similar issues by using a feminine noun to designate someone known to be a man.

Comment: Il n'y a pas, contrairement à l'anglais, de formule neutre pour exprimer cette idée, l'accord doit se faire au féminin. Mais il est tout à fait possible de dire: Monsieur "La prochaine personne" fut cloué sur place de surprise. Cela indique que c'est un homme et aussi qu'on le nomme "La prochaine personne", comme on dit Monsieur "Je sais tout" ([plus](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/M._Je-Sais-Tout)) sous forme de sobriquet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vu que le protagoniste est un homme, pourquoi écrire personne ?

https://crisco2.unicaen.fr/des/synonymes/personne

P. ex.

> Le prochain homme/individu/personnage/âme/mec fut cloué du surprise sur place. « Quel malheur » dit-il. Puis il ferma ses yeux. Enfin, après deux jours, ses amis trouvaient (de même). « Comment vas-tu ? » ils le questionnaient.

Comment: « personnage » is the term, which will solve all the grammatical problems I've got, writing a story where the protagonist was designed as « la prochaine personne » (wanted to be  met by another person). The other possibe solution, as I see, is « le prochain être humain ». Indeed I am looking for a translation of "the next best person" or "the next person, who ever it will be“ - and therefore  the special question is left, if it will be correct  to write: « le prochain meilleur être humain » or « le prochain meilleur personnage » ?

Comment: @Sylvester > Yes it will be correct (you shouldn't have similar gender dilemma), but probably very heavy to write or read.. I would assign him a first name and go with that first name for the rest of the book.

Comment: @ Laurent S. Yes, and here I would like to use one of the other solutions, after introducing him, I would like to give him as proper name « prochain meilleur  », building sentences like: « prochain meilleur » fut cloué du surprise sur place.

Comment: *Pourquoi écrire personne ?* : Tous simplement parce qu'un homme est une personne. Cette contradiction supposée entre genre et sexe peut poser problème à des apprenants mais pas aux francophones natifs. (et *le prochain âme* n'est pas ce qu'on peut proposer de mieux...)

Comment: "*Le prochain homme/individu/personnage/âme/mec fut cloué du surprise sur place*", de surprise plutôt.

Answer (score 7):

[Personne](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personne) est un substantif féminin. Que le protagoniste du conte soit masculin ne change rien aux règles de grammaire !

Les pronoms personnels s'y rapportant doivent donc être accordés au féminin.

> La prochaine personne fut cloué**e** de surprise sur place. « Quel malheur » dit-**elle**. Puis **elle** ferma ses yeux. Enfin, après deux jours, ses amis trouvaient la prochaine personne. « Comment vas-tu ? » ils l**a** questionnaient.

Comment: Merci, mais c'est un problème littéraire. Il est important que le protagoniste du conte est masculin et est nommé ni Peter ni Paul mais « la prochaine personne . » (Le conte  compte 68 p.)

Comment: @Sylvester: Cela ne change rien aux règles de grammaire !

Comment: @Sylvester: Une façon de s'en sortir est de remplacer _personne_ par un nom masculin, par exemple _individu_.

Comment: @Toto:Mmmh - Pas licence poétique pour les petits écrivains en règlement grammaire?

Comment: @Mouviciel: Très intéressant propos, je le  réfléchirai. Grand merci.

Comment: @ho2o2hh2o: c'est fait.

Answer (score 3):

It seem certain that the intention in using "prochaine personne", which to me appears to be inspired by the English "the next guy", is to communicate something special, which unfortunately doesn't come through in French as there is no idiomaticity in this expression, except when talking about the succession of persons likely to have the same fate in  a course of events. Maybe "Monsieur tout le monde" could be the idea, but I doubt it; nevertheless, it seems to me that there is no case for rendering this expression by means of a banal idiomatic substitute and that there is instead an author's problem, that of an author trying to put into words a new idea.
We get back into the domain of perfect idiomaticity if instead of "la prochaine personne" we use "la personne comme une autre", but I don't know whether that's what user Sylvester has really in mind.

The masculine gender can be used and then the reader has to conclude that this person is a male. What would be incongruous, for the least difficult to understand, would be an alternance in the text of feminine and masculine genders.

Comment: A better alternative to transpose "The next guy" might be "Au suivant" rather than "La prochaine personne". I agree this is likely the intention.

Comment: @mins No, « the next guy » is here meant to say "as any other" as in "as the next guy", that is what is intended.     (idiomatic) To a reasonable degree; as much as a typical person or man.

        I like reading as much as the next guy.
        I'm as friendly as the next guy. (Wiktionnaire)

Comment: Now I see it's indeed idiomatic (a bit like *comme tout le monde* or M. Tout-le-monde, in some context).

Answer (score 0):

Tu pourrais résoudre le problème en substituant « dit-il » par « dit l'homme. »

Comment: @toto Tu es certain que ton changement signifie ce que je voulais dire? Je ne crois pas...

Comment: Effectivement, je me suis emmêlé les pinceaux, désolé.

Answer (score 0):

Tout simplement :

> La prochaine personne, un homme, fut cloué**e** de surprise sur place 
>   . « Quel malheur » dit-**il**. Puis **il** ferma ses yeux. …

Pour un conte :

> La prochaine personne, un homme *de grande taille ven**u** d’un pays lointain*, fut cloué**e** de surprise sur place 
>   . « Quel malheur » dit-**il**. Puis **il** ferma **l**es yeux *sous le choc*. Enfin, après deux jours, ses amis **le** trouvaient *par hasard*. « Comment vas-tu ? » **le** questionnaient-ils.

<sup>*Remplacer les mots en italique à sa [guise](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/guise)**.***</sup>